# HTML5 LocalStorage screwing with my variables

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-storage

I'm new to HTML and Javascript, and to learn it I am making an incremental game (similar to CookieClicker or CivClicker).

I'm trying to save and load progress, and I can save it just fine, but when I load it, it loads all the variables correctly, but when I click on a button to increment a variable, it does some weird stuff, it's hard to explain, I'll post the code so you can look at it some more.

**[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Virgoth098/84DSP/)**

```
function loadProgress() {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        progress = localStorage.progress;
        speed = localStorage.speed;
        quality = localStorage.quality;
        isDone = localStorage.isDone;
        totalMoney = localStorage.totalMoney;
        speedCost = localStorage.speedCost;
        gamesSold = localStorage.gamesSold;
        autoclick = localStorage.autoclick;
        autoclickCost = localStorage.autoclickCost;
        currentBugs = localStorage.currentBugs;
        refreshDisplay();
    } else {
        console.log("LocalStore not appliable.")
    }
}
```

Press 'Design' until you get to 100% then click 'Sell your game'. Then just press Save Progress then Load progress and click design and sell game again, you will see the numbers increase very oddly and that isn't expected at all.

'ShowMeTheMoney' will show you the variables in the console so you can verify that the variables were stored correctly.

I have no idea why this is happening, so if someone could help that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Local storage aka Web Storage, stores values as strings, so you need to convert/cast to numbers when you retrieve the values, otherwise the variables will remain as strings, and you'll see concatenation instead of the value being incremented. For example `1 + 1` becomes `11` not `2`.

[Updated working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84DSP/1/)

There are many ways of converting to a number, one way is the `+` method:

```
progress = +localStorage.progress;  
speed = +localStorage.speed;    
quality = +localStorage.quality;
```

Comment: You can use `progress = Number(localStorage.progress);` too.